# Logical elements substitution [3D Matrix]

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say that I have 2 3D-Matrix:

```
A = rand(10,4,100);
B = rand(10,4,100);
L = gt(A,B);
```

Now I want substitute all elements of `B` with elements of `A` only where `L==1`but this doesn't work:

```
B(L==1,:,:) = A(L==1,:,:);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If `L` is always computed as `gt(A,B)`, why not just use `B = max(A,B);`?

Comment: @LuisMendo because I need to know what values has been changed to perform the same operation with other matrices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the `find()` function.

```
p = find(L);
B(p) = A(p);
```

EDIT: Just realized you don't need the `find()` function. Just use logical indexing like this:

```
B(L==1) = A(L==1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Our even shorter whithout *find*

```
B(L) = A(L);
```